# Error when adding dependecy to a trigger.io native plugin

Tags: android, trigger.io

I am developing a native plugin and it depends on an existing library (which was built in maven not sure if it makes a difference). I added the plugin to the libs folder and updated the inspector project. In adt I can see the library being added to the forge inspector plugin in the libs folder but it is not added to the modules build path.

I figured this was caused by the library being absent from my build_steps.json file I added the dependency to the file:

[

```
{
    "do": {
        "android_add_permission": {
            "permission": "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        }
    }
},
{
    "do": {
        "include_dependencies": {
            "leveldb-0.6-SNAPSHOT": {
                "hash": "8e7bd9547206ecca974530109983fc8d"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

]

After adding the dependency I updated the inspector project and got the following error:

Applying build steps failed, check build steps and re-update inspector: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/home/me/forge-workspace/plugins/triggerdb/inspector/.trigger/cache/8e7bd9547206ecca974530109983fc8d.zip'

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a bug we fixed in v1.4.43 of the platform, where libs could end up in the wrong place during the generation of an inspector project.

If you edit `plugin/manifest.json` to update the platform version to `v1.4.43`, then rebuild your inspector, you should be good to go.

Apologies for the `include_dependencies` red herring: I've removed that from our docs until we do the server-side work to enable that step.

Comment: That worked!. Can you go more in depth about the purpose of the include_dependencies and in what situation it would be required in the buid_steps file?